# I developed one jsp page n now I want to change it's UI but even using new css,UI is not change

Tags: jsp

I developed one jsp page ,now I get new UI for this page so I want to change my old UI to new one but after lots of efforts ,even after use of new css,UI is not changing.

please Help me.
Thanks

Comment: Difficult to diagnose what's going on with so little detail and zero code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I developed one jsp page n now I want to change it's UI but even using new css,UI is not change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787869/i-developed-one-jsp-page-n-now-i-want-to-change-its-ui-but-even-using-new-css-u)

Answer (score 1):

If you have already changed the css, then probably there can be some cache issue. Clear your Web Server's cache and may be also your browser cache and then try. There can be also be an issue if you have changed your system date to future date and then made changes and then switched back to original date. Thats when cache is not cleared as what chages you do the timestamp will be less than the date when java file out of jsp was created. In that case also clearing the Server's cache will help.