# I developed one jsp page n now I want to change it's UI but even using new css,UI is not change

Tags: jsp

I developed one jsp page ,now I get new UI for this page so I want to change my old UI to new one but after lots of efforts ,even after use of new css,UI is not changing.

Here is old code for css

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/spacegallery.css" />  --> 
<!-- <link href=" css/dropdown/dropdown.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href=" css/dropdown/themes/default.advanced.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

new code

```
<link href="intra_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

please Help me.
Thanks

Comment: can you tell exactly what you are getting after you apply new style sheet? there may be the case where your new style sheet class names are different from the old one.

Comment: after applying new css ,there is not coming frames for widgets which I want.

Comment: did you check your class names in new CSS file? use firebug or in chrome do inspect element to check what class its applying or not.

Answer (score 0):

Get [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/de/firefox/) and [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) then you can inspect your page completely rendered. Did you take out your old css includes? Like css/main.css and so on? If not then the first declaration of an CSS-Object is applied.

Comment: there are many css that you are using, Replace the old css that is applying to your page with new one.

Comment: Now I delete app previous css and save only new css

Comment: Please follow my instructions and debug the page yourself of load if up somewhere and post the link. With "it's not working" we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

1)make sure that intra_style.css should be in same folder where your jsp exist.
2)Remove all previous CSS includes.
3)Check out Class names of your style sheet are matching Ur HTML Style Class names.

Answer (score 0):

First check the CSS if you can view the code using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox or [Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html) in Google Chrome.

Second: is your `intra_style.css` is the dame folder with your jsp? As I can see on your old CSS it has a folder `css/`. Try it the `href` like this:

```
<link href="css/intra_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Third: Try to delete the cookies/ineternet history on your browser. What I mean is the cache.

Comment: I did the second option and changes occurred,now widgets are coming but their header is not still coming.  Thanks.

Comment: Where did your intra_style.css located? It is on css folder also? and does the header style is in that css file? Did you try the first and third option?

Comment: Ifollowed your steps and now all UI done that I want.Thank you very much.

Comment: now I give sendRedirect() to one servlet page for one jsp page but it does not senredirect and refresh

Comment: How did your redirect it? may be your redirecting on the same page. Or the problem is where you expect. If this another issue, I guess its better to create a new question for that. If what I'm thinking is correct about your problem, I guess its already here SO. Just dig some post here.

Comment: Actually when I click on ask question link,this msg is displaying....Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

Comment: I guess, it because of the way you ask a question. To know more about it. Read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63432/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account and here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68616/so-is-not-accepting-questions-from-my-account-anymore

Comment: I'm not sure also. I find the link that can answer your question about this. See it here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this